# Kendo Grid unable to populate view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, kendo-grid

I am trying to populate a kendo ui grid with data from my database. I cannot find a answer with all the other postings with the same issue. the user does a search using UserId, and To/From Dates. using breakpoints i can see the data coming back through the controller. first time using kendo so if i need to post more information please let me know

Error Message

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Source Error:

Line 11:     .Columns(columns =>
Line 12:     {
Line 13:         columns.Bound(m => m.ActivityDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
Line 14:         columns.Bound(m => m.Assignment);
Line 15:         columns.Bound(m => m.Action);
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReportsPhoneSupport(ReportsPhoneSupport model)
{       
    string[] userIds = model.UserId.Split(',');

    foreach (string userId in userIds)
    {
        int iUserId = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(userId, out iUserId))
        {
            ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView results = new ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView();
            RetrievalProcedures.FetchReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView(results, model.FromDate, model.ToDate, iUserId);
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ReportsPhoneSupport";
 }

<h2>ReportsPhoneSupport</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UtilityWebSite.Controllers.ReportsPhoneSupportController>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.ActivityDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
        columns.Bound(m => m.Assignment);
        columns.Bound(m => m.Action);
        columns.Bound(m => m.ToFrom);
        columns.Bound(m => m.Result);
        columns.Bound(m => m.Description);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReportsPhoneSupport", "ReportsPhoneSupport"))
    )
)
```

CLASS

```
 public class ReportsPhoneSupport
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

}
```

}[image: Data From SQL]

Comment: Have posted an answer but will expand if you can give me a bit info as to your model class and what you want to happen on the read as in server filtering, passing in filters that are outside of the grid etc.

Comment: the search result brings in 2 results. 1 for each user ID

Comment: Hopefully my extended example points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to be returning Json to the grid and not a view.

So something like

```
Public jsonresult readData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, MyModel model)
{
 Do something here to get data for source
 Eg List<MyReturnedModel> returnModel = new List<MyReturnedModel>()
 { new MyReturnedModel(){ id = 1}, (etc)
  };

Return json(returnedModel.ToDataSourceResult(request,ModelState), jsonbehaviour.Get);
}
```

Hopefully this will give you enough of an idea to run with.

Edit:

I also noticed you are setting the controller class as the grid entity when it should be your model class.

second edit:

ok so if I have this right the actual data being shown on the grid should be of Type **ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView**

so if you change the grid first to this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<**ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView**>()
 (include any namespaces here for the model type to be referenced correctly.)
 .Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(m => m.ActivityDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Assignment);
    columns.Bound(m => m.Action);
    columns.Bound(m => m.ToFrom);
    columns.Bound(m => m.Result);
    columns.Bound(m => m.Description);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperations(true)
   .Read(read => read.Action("ReportsPhoneSupport", "ReportsPhoneSupport").Data("MyFilters"))
)
```

)

You will notice I added the .Data after your read action and using some javascript you can add your search parameters

so something like this:

```
<script>
function MyFilters()
{
     return { filterModel: {   
                               UserId: 1,
                               ToDate: "01 Jan 2014",
                               FromDate: "20 Jan 2014"
                            }
            };
}
</script>
```

This then should construct the model object you are passing back to perform you filtering and then change you read action to something like this:

Note Make sure you include the namespace Kendo.Mvc.Extensions and Kendo.Mvc.UI into the controller for the DataSourceRequest/ toDataSourceResult to be picked up correctly.

```
public JsonResult ReportsPhoneSupport([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,ReportsPhoneSupport filterModel )
{       
   string[] userIds = filterModel.UserId.Split(',');

foreach (string userId in userIds)
{
    int iUserId = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(userId, out iUserId))
    {
        ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView results = new ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView();
        RetrievalProcedures.FetchReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView(results, filterModel.FromDate, filterModel.ToDate, iUserId);
    }
}
  **I am assuming your results set is some form of enumerable/IList**
return Json( results.toDataSourceResult(request,ModelState), jsonbehaviour.AllowGet);
```

}

Hopefully this expanded example should give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: that is a lot of help! thank you.however I am getting this message on the return Json(results.toDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);        The Name 'results' does not exist in the current context

Comment: the results initialization needs to be setup outside of the foreach loop and then this should work. so just more the first line ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView results = new ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView(); out of the foreach loop.

Comment: that solved the problem. however i am getting      A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type     when I search for results. Wouldn't paging take care of this?

Comment: If this object is being pulled from an ORM like EF or Data Access then you will need to present a flattened view model it is explained in this link: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-avoid-circular-reference-exceptions?

Comment: Not a problem. I had a similar issue when I was starting out with the kendo MVC wrappers.